# Where can you get good quality chocolates in Malaysia?

Tags: food-and-drink, malaysia

Please include names of any local varieties which taste great and list places where you can get cheap chocolates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Housecleaning". The question was posed in 2012 asking for a list. These types of questions are no longer well-received and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beryl's](http://www.berylschocolate.com/) tastes good to me, especially their Tiramisu line.

I bought it in Thailand, but it's made in Malaysia, so it should be widely available.

Answer (score 3):

For cheap chocolate, I will usually go for Langkawi. Few chocolate merchant like Haji Ismail Group (HIG) can be found around Langkawi and HQ at Kuah, where they sell quite number of local and international brand at very cheap price. (e.g. cheapest Daim is around RM 17 - Jan 2014)

For local made chocolate, I will go for Beryl's.
The factory is in Serdang (around 25KM from KL) where I can buy all type of chocolate they produce at better price.

Answer (score 1):

A search reveals two oft-mentioned Malaysian chocolate companies:

- The [Cocoa Boutique](http://cocoaboutique.com.my/) - "the largest chocolate paradise in Malaysia with over 8 outlets located all over the country. Having visited by over 4 million visitors worldwide, Cocoa Boutique continues to expand it’s chocolate ‘empire’ across Malaysia with over 300 different types of delectable chocolates."
- [Beryl's Chocolate Kingdom](http://www.berylschocolate.com/) - "offers more than 100 varieties of chocolate to suit your every mood and desire."

Both websites look absolutely amazing! :)